# How to make div open/close slow?

Tags: javascript

once again in a pickle. I have this js that I would like to when open and close it does it slow. As it is, it just snaps open and close. I tried SlideUp, slideDown, slow but it's always the wrong placement. Much appreciated. Ty.

The button:

```
<div class="open_child" title="', $txt['sub_boards2'], '"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></div>
```

js:

```
      $("document").ready(function () {
        $(".manualclose").click(function(){
        $(".child_box").toggle();
          });

      ls = localStorage.getItem('on')
      if(ls){
        $(".child_box").show()
      }

      $(".open_child").click(function(){
          localStorage.setItem('on',true)
          toggled = $(".child_box").toggle();
          if(toggled.is(":hidden")){
            localStorage.clear();
          }
      });
      $(".manualclose").click(function(){
        localStorage.clear();
        $(".child_box").hide()

      });
   })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `.show()` and `.hide()` will take a duration parameter that will fade in or out the target over that number of milliseconds.

E.g.

```
$( ".target" ).show(500);
```

There are lots of other things you can do, too. Take a look at the [jQuery reference manual](https://api.jquery.com/show/) for details.

Comment: It seems is not respecting Local Storage.  .child_box supposed to remember user's choice either open or closed. It slides but when refreshing page , local storage is not active.

Comment: It slides if go like this,  toggled = $(".child_box").toggle(500); but local storage is not working.

Comment: Nothing happens when used like this, $(".child_box").show(500) and $(".child_box").hide(500)

Comment: It works in [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/37jk6msb/1/)

Comment: Ya, the issue seems to be with Local storage. It doesn't remembers "slow", toggleUp or down.

Comment: Your question was about how to show or hide an element slowly.  I've answered that (`.toggle(500)`is also valid). Your problem with honouring the localStorage setting is not related. You should ask about that as a separate question.